# How can I modify my line of code to return sequential data?

Tags: r

My current code:

```
Value <- lapply((data.frame('ValueUsed' = Table[sample(nrow(Table),1),1], stringsAsFactors = F)), as.character)
```

So the above code will return a row of randomized data from my Table (a dataframe) in Value$ValueUsed, where I will then be using it in a for(i in 1:1000) line to to be used in a function.

However, instead of it being random, I want it to go in the sequence of how it is placed in the Table. How should I go about doing this?

EDIT:
Sample Table

```
Value
123
182
102
320
```

So the code should preferably give me a sequential data when I loop it, going from 123, 182, 102, 320, ...

How my code currently looks like:

```
  for (i in 1:100) {
Value <- lapply((data.frame('ValueUsed' = Table[sample(nrow(Table),1),1], stringsAsFactors = F)), as.character

update(Value$ValueUsed)
}
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Do you want to `sample` ?  It is not clear when you say sequential data preferably

Comment: I need my for statement to run with the update function to run by taking the values in sequential order. So i = 1 should have "123" to be used in update, i = 2 should have "182" used in update, so on and so forth.

Comment: If that is the case, why can't you loop over sequence i.e. `for(i in seq_along(Table$Value))`